# Test @OneToMany in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

I have following entities:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    public BaseEntity(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean isNew(){
        return this.id == null;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project extends BaseEntity{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column
    @NotBlank(message = "Name property cannot be null or empty")
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @Column
    private LocalDateTime created;

    @Column
    private Long parentId;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentId", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Project> subprojects = new HashSet<>();

    @Builder
    public Project(Long id, String name, String description, LocalDateTime created, Long parentId) {
        super(id);
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.created = created;
        this.parentId = parentId;
}
```

and usual repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project, Long>{
}
```

and here is integration test class:

```
@DataJpaTest
class ProjectRepositoryIT {
    
    @Autowired
    TestEntityManager testEntityManager;
    
    @Autowired
    ProjectRepository projectRepository;
    
    @Test
    @Transactional
    void testSaveSubproject() {
        Project parent = Project.builder().name("parent").build();
        parent = testEntityManager.persistAndFlush(parent);
        
        Project child = Project.builder().name("child").parentId(parent.getId()).build();
        child = testEntityManager.persistAndFlush(child);
        
        var optionalParent = projectRepository.findById(parent.getId());
        
        if(optionalParent.isPresent()) {
            var foundParent = optionalParent.get();
            
            assertEquals(parent.getId(), foundParent.getId());
            assertEquals(1, foundParent.getSubprojects().size());
            
            Optional<Project> matchigProject = foundParent.getSubprojects()
                .stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getId().equals(foundParent.getId()))
                .findFirst();
            
            assertTrue(matchigProject.isPresent());
    
            assertEquals(child.getId(), matchigProject.get().getId());
        }else {
            fail("cannot find parent project");
        }
    }
}
```

**Issue**

I'm trying to test if subprojects can be marked properly by set `parentId` property. I expect when `parentId` property is set then project with this `id` should has information about subproject in `subprojects` list. Unfortunately assertion `assertEquals(1, foundParent.getSubprojects().size());` fails because list size is 0. I would like to ask for any advice what I'm doing wrong? I need to announce that I'm pretty new in Spring.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quiet common mistake.
To make it work you may do the following hot fix:

```
    Project parent = Project.builder().name("parent").build();
    Project child = Project.builder().name("child").build();
    parent.getSubprojects().add(child);

    parent = testEntityManager.persistAndFlush(parent);

    child.setParentId(parent.getId());
    child = testEntityManager.persistAndFlush(child);
```

Spring does NOT bind parentId in child entity with set of subprojects in parent entity automatically, there is no magic. You have to put child entity in set of subprojects of a parent entity save it and then set parentId of a child entity by yourself and manage it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Alex Crazy for your answer. My goal was to make it as simple as possible. I want that every `Project` has reference to parent and when parent is deleted then all childs are deleted too.

I fix in following way:

Class `Project` has only `parentId` field without any `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToOne` linkage:

```
...
public class Project extends BaseEntity{
...
    @Column
    private Long parentId;
...
}
```

Then `ProjectRepository` is extended by following search:

```
@Repository
public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project, Long>{
    
    List<Project> findAllByParentId(Long id);
    
    void deleteAllByParentId(Long id);
}
```

And tests:

```
    @Test
    void testFindSubprojects() {
        // Prepare database
        Project parent = Project.builder().name("parent").build();
        parent = testEntityManager.persistAndFlush(parent);
        
        Project child = Project.builder().name("child").parentId(parent.getId()).build();
        child = testEntityManager.persistAndFlush(child);
        
        // Call repository
        Project foundParent = projectRepository.findById(parent.getId()).orElseThrow(() -> fail());
        assertNotNull(foundParent.getId());
        
        List<Project> subprojects = projectRepository.findAllByParentId(foundParent.getId());
        assertEquals(1, subprojects.size());
        assertEquals(child.getId(), subprojects.get(0).getId());
        assertEquals(child.getParentId(), foundParent.getId());
    }
    
    @Test
    void testDeleteAllByParentId() {
        // Prepare database
        Project parent = Project.builder().name("parent").build();
        parent = testEntityManager.persistAndFlush(parent);
        
        testEntityManager.persistAndFlush(Project.builder().name("child1").parentId(parent.getId()).build());
        testEntityManager.persistAndFlush(Project.builder().name("child2").parentId(parent.getId()).build());
        testEntityManager.persistAndFlush(Project.builder().name("child3").parentId(parent.getId()).build());
        
        var subprojects = projectRepository.findAllByParentId(parent.getId());
        assertEquals(3, subprojects.size());
        
        projectRepository.deleteAllByParentId(parent.getParentId());
        
        subprojects = projectRepository.findAllByParentId(parent.getParentId());
        assertEquals(0, subprojects.size());
    }
```

Deleting ass nested subproject will be managed by service layer. I hope that's good solution.